# Visualforce Remoting Exception: Input too long

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

I am getting the following error while trying to upload an excel file. What would be the best way of reducing the size of request?

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193799&language=en_US

[image]

Comment: You need to break the files into chunk then you can pass that

Answer (score 2):

You can use action function instead of visualforce remotting.

Example:

Page:

```
<apex:actionfunction name="js_functionName" action="{!apexMethod}" >
<apex:param name="apexvariableName" value="" assignTo="{!apexvariableName}"/>
```

Java-Script:

```
js_functionName(longInputs);
```

Controller:

```
public string apexvariableName{get;set;}

public void apexMethod(){

   //Input parameter can be accessed using apexvariableName variable
}
```